# How to use find command with sed and awk to remove duplicate IP from files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, awk

Howdie do,

I'm writing a script that will remove duplicate IP's from two files. For example,

```
 grep -rw "123.234.567" /home/test/ips/
 /home/test/ips/codingte:123.234.567
 /home/test/ips/codingt2:123.234.567
```

Ok, so that IP is in two different files and so I need to remove the IP from the second file.

The grep gives me the file path and the IP address. My thinking: store the file path in a variable with awk and then use find to go to that file and use sed to remove the duplicate IP, so I changed my grep statement to:

```
 grep -rw "123.234.567" . | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
```

which returns:

```
 ./codingte
 ./codingt2
```

I originally tried to use the fully pathname in the find command, but that didn't work either

```
 find -name /var/cpanel/dips/codingte -exec sed '/123.234.567/d' {} \;
```

So, I just did a CD in the directory and changed the find command to:

```
 find -name 'codingt2' -exec sed '/123.234.567/d' {} \;
```

Which runs, but doesn't delete the IP address:

```
 cat codingt2
 123.234.567
```

Now, I know the issue is with the dots in the IP address. They need to be escaped, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've been reading for hours on escaping the regex, but I'm not sure how to do this with sed

Any help would be appreciated. I'm just trying to learn more about regex and using them with other linux tools such as awk and find.

I haven't written the full script yet. I'm trying to break it into pieces and then bring it together in the script.

So you know what the output should look like:

```
 codingte
 123.234.567

 codingt2
```

The second file would just have the IP removed

Comment: Could you show what you want the output to look like? I think you want to keep the file names, but just not show a repeat IP more than once (?).

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the entry to show what it I'm looking for here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat FILE1.txt | while read IP ; do sed -i "/^${IP}$/d" FILE2.txt ; done
```

The command does the following:

- There are two files: `FILE1.txt` and `FILE2.txt`
- It will remove in `FILE2.txt` lines (in your case, IP addresses) found in `FILE1.txt`

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you explain the sed? I know the -i option, but I'm just a bit confused by the regex. I know the ^ means line begins iwth. The $ is line ends with, but you also have another $ after the IP which is the confusing part for me

Comment: - I used a while loop to go through each line of `FILE1.txt`
- And for each iteration of the loop, I set the line to arbitrarily be variable `IP` ... this means I can refer to the line as `IP`
- With this being said, the following command is also perfectly valid: `cat FILE1.txt | while read LINE ; do sed -i "/^${LINE}$/d" FILE2.txt ; done`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. The abritrary variable is the index you're using to loop through. So does that mean the way you pass a variable to sed is by enclosing the variable with ${}$

Comment: To pass variables into `sed` you need to use *double* quotes (not single quotes). The curly brackets are not necessary -- it's a byproduct of my style of coding (i.e. you can replace the command with `... sed -i "/^$IP$/d" ...` and it should work fine). The second `$` denotes the end of line and is not involved with the variable.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but I do like the style of coding. Makes it easier to read. So that regex is basically  saying there is a $IP on each line then? That the ^ states the line begins with an IP and the $ is that it ends with an IP? Thank you for your patience with me on this

Answer (score 1):

You want `grep -l` which only print the filenames containing a match:

```
grep -lrw "123.234.567" /home/test/ips/
```

would print

```
/home/test/ips/codingte
/home/test/ips/codingt2
```

So, to skip the first file and work on the rest:

```
grep -l ... | sed 1d | while IFS= read -r filename; do
    whatever with "$filename"
done
```

Comment: Glenn, thank you. The grep -l does just return the file names, so thank you for that and the sed 1d gets me to the second line, but I'm a bit confused by the rest of your reply

Comment: that's the placeholder where you do the stuff you need to do to remove the IP from the "duplicate" files

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the -i argument to sed to edit the files in place.

echo foo > test
find -name test -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/' {} \;

seems to do the trick.

Comment: I'm not looking to do a swap. But literally delete the duplicate entry in the second file

Comment: Your line works for the deletion of the line. The problem is that the file is not edited.