# Sed getting stuck in infinite loop after removing entry from file

Tags: bash, loops, sed, awk

Howdie do,

I'm currently working on a script that will take a list of IPs, store them in a LIST, loop through that list and compare the IP's to those in two text files. If the IP is duplicated in both files, it will remove the IP from one of the files.

The two files that contain the duplicates:

```
 cat jeremy
 209.240.105.0

 cat jeremy2
 209.240.105.0
```

Now the code is pretty simple:

```
 LIST="$(cat /STORAGE/ips | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')"

 for I in $LIST
  do
         DUP1=$(grep -rwl "$I" /STORAGE/jeremy/ | awk -F '/' '{print $4}' | sed 2d)
         DUP2=$(grep -rwl "$I" /STORAGE/jeremy/ | awk -F '/' '{print $4}' | sed 1d)
         cat $DUP1 | while read IP; do sed -i "/^${IP}$/d" $DUP2 ; done
 done
```

That actually works and removes the duplicate IP from the $DUP2 file as it should, but it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop.

I saw this as after I run the script, it will remove the duplicate as it should, but the script just keeps running.

If you press enter while the script is turning it's wheels, it spits out:

```
 sed: no input files

 sed: no input files
```

But you can clearly see the duplicate IP has been removed:

```
 [/STORAGE/jeremy]# cat jeremy
 [/STORAGE/jeremy]# cat jeremy2
                    209.240.105.0
```

So it does it's job, but the sed command seems to be stuck in a loop. I've only today really started to learn more about sed it's capabilites, but is there an equivalent to break; like c++ or c#?

I just need sed to break out of the while read loop

The Input and Output files are posted below and also, this is not a duplicate question. I did raise a question earlier about this script, but that was just to get better understanding of how to use the regex with the sed and awk.

IP Input file that generates $LIST

```
 209.240.105.0:255.255.255.255:209.240.105.0
 209.240.105.1:255.255.255.255:209.240.105.1
```

The two files that I'm testing on just contain a list of one IP at the time:

```
 Test file #1 jeremy:

 209.240.105.0

 Test file #2 jeremy2:

 209.240.105.0
```

Once the script runs, it should only remove the IP from the Test File #2:

```
 Test file #1 jeremy:

 209.240.105.0

 Test file #2 jeremy2:
```

Which the script currently does. It's just that I have to kill the script manually instead of it breaking out of the while read loop

Comment: When `${I}` has a value that isn't found in one of the files, what will be the value of `${DUP2}`? Due to `sed 2d`, `${DUP1}` will contain the name of one of the file, but `${DUP2}` is not guaranteed to contain a filename because of `sed 1d`. What's the point of the outer loop `for I in $LIST` when you're already reading all the entries in file 1 and comparing to every line in file 2 in the inner `while loop`?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057394/how-to-use-find-command-with-sed-and-awk-to-remove-duplicate-ip-from-files

Comment: It seems for me that all this code could be done by one simple `awk`.  Post all files, Jeremy, IPS etc.  And post who the output should be.  You should not `cat` file to `awk`, use:  `LIST=$(awk -F ':' '{print $1}' /STORAGE/ips)`.

Comment: You can't use grep for this since grep works on REs so every `.` in an IP address will be treated as the RE metacharacter that matches any single character. You need to use `fgrep` or `awk/index()` or instead, or escape the `.`s. There's several other problems and opportunities for improvement - as Jotne suggests, post your input files and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: I've updated the information to show you exactly what I"m looking for. Also, not a duplicate question here. I asked a question yesterday on getting my commands written properly. Now I'm just trying to figure out why the script spins its wheels after removing the IP

Comment: My money is on `cat` waiting for you to type input to it.  You don't ensure that there's a value in `$DUP1` before trying to `cat` the file.  The `sed` command also has issues if `$DUP2` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this, uses GNU awk for "\<" word-delimiters:

```
gawk -F':' '
NR==FNR{ gsub(/\./,"\\."); ips["\\<" $1 "\\>"]; next }
{
    for (ip in ips) {
        if ( match($0,ip) ) {
            print ip, FILENAME, RSTART, RLENGTH
        }
    }
}
' /STORAGE/ips /STORAGE/jeremy/* |
sort
```

That should print, for each IP address, the file name(s) it occurs in plus the character position it first occurs in on each line, and the length of the IP address.

Does it?

Once you post some sample input and expected output we can go further.

Comment: Ok, but the issue here isn't getting the IPs. It's not even getting the location of the IPs. The dupiclate will only occur in two files hence why I only have two variables. That portion is completely fine and I've throughly tested it. The issue is when the sed command runs, it removes the duplicate and never breaks out of sed

Comment: I understand that's the question you have, but the script has other issues too that you may not have hit yet with your data and files to date but which probably will bite you down the road. We could peel the onion for a long time trying to make that script work or just start over and do it in way that will work reliably.